# How to Run android AVD from servlet

Tags: android, servlets

I want to run/launch the AVD from servlet. 
    I have a class,

```
class A extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2{ 

    // all the relevant function for launching the ADV and execution of test steps in android app.

}
```

This class is working fine when i run as Android JUnit Test. but i want to call/run this class from servlet.

Like : I have a servlet,

```
B extends HttpServlet {

    doPost() {
        A obj = new A();
        obj.somemethod()  which launch the ADV or open the application.
    }
}
```

But when i excute it from the servlet i got exception

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/test/ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
                                                                                         org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2818)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1148)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1643)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
com.web.evernote.ui.bean.ExecuteTestCases.doPost(ExecuteTestCases.java:83)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Could any one can help me out in this....

basically i want to run the adv and then open the activity like notepad and want to perform the test....

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the ADB command to launch the emulator, in somemethod()  function you need something like this:

```
strCommand.append(ADB_PATH + "adb -s "+simulatorName+" shell am instrument ");;
strCommand.append("-w ");
strCommand.append(instrumentationPath); 
try
{
    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(strCommand.toString());
    p.waitFor();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The above example initiates a test case on an emulator.
here strCommand is an instance of StringBuilder. ADB_PATH is a variable that stores adb path. What you will have to do is change the command to start the emulator. Something like this

adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n org.sample.helloworld/org.sample.helloworld.HelloWorld.

Comment: Thanks, Actually i can run the ADV via exec as you mentioned. but i am getting issue after this... my code is : try {
                        launcherActivityClass = Class.forName(launch activity class name );
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }

Comment: To launch the device use emulator -avd emulator-5558 command, where emulator-5558 is the name of AVD.

Comment: After that you can use this command:  adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n org.sample.helloworld/org.sample.helloworld.HelloWorld. This will open HelloWorld activity